# How to tell the Macros to execute the script for all rows and not just a set amount of rows?

Tags: excel, vba

Macros are new to me. I'm working on a Macros project where the number of rows varies constantly. However, the number of Columns will not change.
The problem is the script only runs for a set amount of rows. Debugging revealed that it operates according to how macros were recorded. Here is my sample code -

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J559")
```

So it executes only upto 559 records. How can I get the script to execute for every row?

Comment: Find the last row first, and then substitute the variable holding that value for the `559` - `Range("J2:J" & lastRow)`

Comment: How do I do this? I am not a developer. Thanks